# Pass muliple args to a python script spawned from node.js

Tags: node.js, spawn

I am trying to "spawn" a python script in Node.JS. The python script accepts multiple file paths as args. This command works:

```
python3 script.py 'path1' 'path2' 'path3'
```

In node, I am given a var with the paths:

```
args = ["path1", "path2", "path3"]
```

But when I try to spawn the script:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var pyspawn = spawn(
  'python3', [pyscript.py, args]
);
```

But this appears to issue the command:

```
python3 script.py [path1,path2,path3]
```

Tinkering with various concat()s, join()s, and toString()s I can get stuff that looks like:

```
python3 script.py "'path1' 'path2' 'path3'"
```

... but cant for the life of me figure how to do this simply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) might be what you are looking for.

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the new array.

Try the following:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pyFile = 'script.py';
const args = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3'];
args.unshift(pyFile);
const pyspawn = spawn('python3', args);

pyspawn.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

pyspawn.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

pyspawn.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. I teased around this, but never made that leap -- include the pyfile in the list at the outgo!